# Do we call one machine as datanode and nodemanager?

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

HDFS has two nodes namenodes and datanodes. And YARN has one resource manager and nodemanager.
I want to know are these entites on single machine. Like namenode and resource manager on one machine together. Datanode and nodemanager together on other machine. As per my understanding client requests namenode for the information where data is stored, which is similar to asking for resource manager for resources. And datanode contains data, which is wat nodemanager contains on which map reduce jobs are executed.

Please correct me if my understanding of HDFS is wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Namenode, Datanode, ResourceManger and NodeManager all are service running on different Nodes/Machines.
There is no hard and fast rule that these Services need to run on different machines or combination of two/three on same machine, It is upto the admin, How he wants to deploy, You can definitely have them running together on same Nodes/Machine. Nothing specific that Datanode and NodeManager on same node/Machine and Namenode/ResourceManager on different same machines.
You can have all of them on seprate machines, any of them together, say Namenode and Datanode together, and ResourceManager and NodeManager together, depending upon the resources(Memory/vCores) available on the machine.

For HDFS Architecture :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html

For YARN Architecture :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html

Note.Namenode and Datanode are part of HDFS, which is the storage layer, and ResourceManager and NodeManager are part of YARN, which is a Resource Negotiator. So HDFS and YARN though works together usually but are quite independent at design and architecture